# Installing a package by copying and pasting into directory for Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install the fix_data_yahoo package from the following website

https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/#files

and I copied the extracted contents to my Users\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages directory but I am unable to import the package in Anaconda3, Spyder.

I do not know how to clone this from Github but was told that I could copy and paste the files into the appropriate folder and could run the package after that. I am trying to avoid using 'pip' to install the package. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Should I extract the tar.gz file or should I put it as a tar.gz file in the directory?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: I'm not sure, why you want to do it manually. You can simply run  `pip install  --no-cache-dir fix_yahoo_finance` when your conda environment is activated.

Comment: I want to avoid using pip because it trigger other problems for Anaconda

Comment: What problems in particular?

Comment: If you don't want to use pip, you can alway `git clone` [the repository](https://github.com/ranaroussi/fix-yahoo-finance) and run `setup.py` in an activated environment.

Comment: How do I use git clone? Please tell me because I really don't know much about this

Comment: People have written that using conda makes more sense for Anaconda compared to pip but conda fails for this particular package

Comment: I just decided to follow your advice about pip after doing some more reading. IT worked. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should use `conda` to install software into your conda environments, but not all Python packages are present in conda repos. In that case it is okay to use `pip`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EliKorvigo